# MongoServerError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have 3 mongo collections with a field in common (in each collection the field takes different values so it is not possible any join). I would like to sum the distinct values that the field takes in each collection; something like: distinct_value_col1 + distinct_value_col2 + distinct_value_col3

this is what I tried:

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    '$facet': {
      'query1':
        db.col1.aggregate([
        {
        '$group': {
          _id: "$field",
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
        },
        {
        '$group': {
          _id: null,
          distinctCount: { $sum: 1 }
        }
        }
        ]).toArray(),
      'query2': 
        db.col2.aggregate([
          {
            '$group': {
              _id: "$field",
              count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          },
          {
            '$group': {
              _id: null,
              distinctCount: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
        ]).toArray()
    }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      total: {
        '$add': ["$query1.distinctCount", "$query2.distinctCount"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Do you have any idea how to solved that?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two queries. And the error message does not match to your code, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/yeUOpgzwch_ gives *PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $add only supports numeric or date types, not array*

Comment: sorry I copied to times the tutorial solution Now I copied mine

Comment: $facet does not work, you need [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)

Comment: one of the greatest thing of MongoDB is you can join collections even if there is nothing key reference. you may wanna put an example data for each collections

Answer (score 0):

That query is a mix of javascript code and JSON.  The aggregate function requires an array of objects, each representing a single stage of the aggregation.

For the aggregation you are showing, it would probably be more efficient to use `distinct` and sum on the client side, like:

```
db.col1.distinct("field").length + db.col2.distinct("field").length
```

Comment: this is the first attempt I tried but for some reason it was not working. Now it works thanks a lot